# Fatal Error when importing any .img- Amlogic USB burning tool, v2.0.8, v2.0.9, v2.1.2 Windows 10

Tags: android, windows

Amlogic USB burning tool v2.0.8, v2.0.9, v2.1.2- Fatal Error when importing any image. Windows 10

I was able to flash my Nexbox A95X (s905x) 2Gb Ram 8gb storage once yesterday. The next day I tried to flash my second box which is a 2gb Ram 16gb storage same model. But before I plug in the box by USB transfer cable, I have to import the .img firmware file into the USB burning tool program. When I import any .img file into the USB Tool program, it closes with a pop up that basically says Fatal error, please check crash.dmp.

Here is my crash.dmp file which can be downloaded here:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=05475691369172656462

I always install the USB burning tool as administrator and run it as administrator. I tried installing a newer version of the USB burning tool program on top of the current installation. I uninstalled the USB burning tool and the libusb driver it installed. Then I used ccleaner to clear the cache and fix the registries. I even tried uninstalling the USB burning tool with Revo uninstaller in advanced mode and it deleted all related files and registries using revo uninstaller. I tried deleting the log file. Nothing I have done has fixed it.

Can any of you please tell me what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I fixed it by doing this:

- uninstall usb burning tool
- delete Amlogic folder in `c:/Program Files (x86)/`
- delete Amlogic Inc. in `regedit HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software`